# Lightning Flow Display text does not render HTML inside lightning out app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-out

I have a flow that is using a simple `DisplayText` element on the Screen. It just displays **Hello world** (yes, I formatted it to be bold). I edited the record detail page and added this flow to the page. On the record detail page it shows correctly.

On another page, where I used a lightning Out container app, and embedded this flow using an aura component, the displayText element on the flow does not show up correctly. It renders the html with escaped characters. So on the browser, I see
`<p><b>Hello World</b></p>`.

This is how I am dynamically creating the component

```
$Lightning.use('LightningOutContainerApp')
              .then(function() {
                var attributes = {};
                  $Lightning.createComponent('c:myComponent', attributes, 'my-container')
                  .then(function(component) {
                    // tear down the component on destroying scope.
                  })
                  .catch(function(e) {
                    console.error('Failed to create component', e);
                  });
              });
```

`LightningOutContainerApp` is my aura app. `my-container` is the dom node, where I want the component to be attached to. Code simplified for brevity.

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
  <aura:dependency resource="c:myComponent" type="COMPONENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

Reference:
How to embed a flow in an aura component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_lc.htm

Comment: Turns that, this happens only on certain salesforce orgs. I am still figuring out if there might be a setting in Security or Session that is affecting the sanitization of html.